Kotlin multiplatform gradle sync issues
Since i started learning to use kotlin multiplatform with compose, im having issues with gradle sync all the time and i would like to know what it means. im posting an example error but it happened with many libraries, and even with those which were fine just a week ago. Therefore i would like know what im doing wrong so i can move on
Example error:
:composeApp:iosArm64Main: Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3.
Required by:
project :composeApp > com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0 > androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0 > androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.8.5
build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.ktorfit)
    alias(libs.plugins.buildkonfig)
    alias(libs.plugins.serialization)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_22)
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
            implementation(libs.androidx.compose.google.fonts)
            implementation(libs.ktorfit)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
            implementation(libs.ktorfit.converters.call)
            implementation(libs.qr.kit)
            implementation(libs.androidx.navigation)
            implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "xxx"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "xxx"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "0.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_22
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_22
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.15"
    }

}

dependencies {
    debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
}

buildkonfig {
    packageName = "xxx"

    xxx

    }

}


libs.versons.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.7.2"
android-compileSdk = "35"
android-minSdk = "31"
android-targetSdk = "34"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.9.3"
androidx-appcompat = "1.7.0"
androidx-constraintlayout = "2.2.0"
androidx-core-ktx = "1.15.0"
androidx-espresso-core = "3.6.1"
androidx-lifecycle = "2.8.4"
androidx-test-junit = "1.2.1"
androidx-material = "1.12.0"
androidx-compose-google-fonts="1.7.5"
androidx-navigation = "2.8.0-alpha10"
compose-multiplatform = "1.7.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
kotlin = "2.0.21"
ktorfit = "2.2.0"
ksp = "2.0.21-1.0.28"
okio = "3.9.1"
buildkonfig = "0.15.2"
serialization-json = "1.7.3"
qrkit = "3.0.5"

[libraries]
kotlin-test = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-test-junit = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit", version.ref = "kotlin" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "androidx-core-ktx" }
androidx-test-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "androidx-test-junit" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "androidx-espresso-core" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "androidx-appcompat" }
androidx-compose-google-fonts = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-text-google-fonts", version.ref = "androidx-compose-google-fonts"}
androidx-compose-material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material" , version.ref = "androidx-material"}
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "androidx-constraintlayout" }
androidx-activity-compose = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "androidx-activityCompose" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel = { group = "org.jetbrains.androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-viewmodel", version.ref = "androidx-lifecycle" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-compose = { group = "org.jetbrains.androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-compose", version.ref = "androidx-lifecycle" }
androidx-navigation = { group = "org.jetbrains.androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-compose", version.ref = "androidx-navigation"}
ktorfit = { group = "de.jensklingenberg.ktorfit", name = "ktorfit-lib", version.ref = "ktorfit"}
squareup-okio = { group = "com.squareup.okio", name = "okio", version.ref = "okio" }
buildkonfig = { group = "com.codingfeline.buildkonfig", name = "buildkonfig-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "buildkonfig"}
kotlinx-serialization-json = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx", name = "kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "serialization-json"}
ktorfit-converters-call = { group = "de.jensklingenberg.ktorfit", name = "ktorfit-converters-call", version.ref = "ktorfit"}
qr-kit = { group = "network.chaintech", name = "qr-kit", version.ref = "qrkit"}

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
composeMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-multiplatform" }
composeCompiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
ktorfit = { id = "de.jensklingenberg.ktorfit", version.ref = "ktorfit" }
buildkonfig = { id = "com.codingfeline.buildkonfig", version.ref = "buildkonfig"}
jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }
serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin"}


Some kind of network issue? There is more to such error messages, where it will tell you where it looked for such libraries and couldn't find them.

Dont think its a network issue as everything else is fine, is it possible that given library is only available to use with android but not with IOS?

Ah well, yes there is such a potential error as Gradle/the Kotlin plugin will match the library variant so it won't work to add an Android-only library to an iOS source set. This is spelt out in such an error message, though you may have clipped off the bit that explains that in the above

thats actually whole error as i got it, nothing else, no details. And nowhere to be  found what that actually means
